# Independence of two sets (relative complements)

Tags: probability, solution-verification, independence

Let events $X$ and $Y$ be independent such that $\mathbb{P}(X) \in (0,1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y) \in (0,1)$. Check the independence of events $X \setminus Y$ and $Y \setminus X$.

So $X \setminus Y \perp Y \setminus X$ if and only if $$\mathbb{P}((Y \setminus X) \cap (X \setminus Y)) = \mathbb{P}(Y \setminus X) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X \setminus Y))$$

1. using Venn diagram, $(Y \setminus X) \cap (X \setminus Y) = \emptyset$, so $$\mathbb{P}((Y \setminus X) \cap (X \setminus Y)) = 0$$
2. $\mathbb{P}(Y \setminus X) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X \setminus Y)$ = $[\mathbb{P}(Y) - \mathbb{P}(X \cap Y)]\cdot [\mathbb{P}(X) - \mathbb{P}(Y \cap X)] \overset{\text{independence X, Y}}{=} [\mathbb{P}(Y) - \mathbb{P}(Y)\mathbb{P}(X)]\cdot [\mathbb{P}(X) - \mathbb{P}(Y)\mathbb{P}(X)] > 0$

because $$\mathbb{P}(Y) - \mathbb{P}(Y)\mathbb{P}(X) >0 $$ and $$\mathbb{P}(X) - \mathbb{P}(X)\mathbb{P}(Y) >0$$ as $\mathbb{P}(X) \in (0,1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y) \in (0,1)$

Thus events $X \setminus Y$ and $Y \setminus X$ are NOT independent. Am I correct?

Comment: Don't you mean to say in your last line that the events are **not** independent?

Comment: @drhab you are right!

Comment: Then you are correct.